# Slide effect of element with finger on Android

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, draggable

I am trying to find out what is the best approach for sliding effect of some element on the screen on Android device.

I read about drag and drop of the elements, but I am not sure is that the correct approach or I should go for Canvas.

Or should I use some events like onTouch, and then enter my logic which will move the elements.

I am looking for some solution to make this "sliding" really smooth.

The thing that I want to make is moving of the elements in some matrix, with simple slide. (for example, if I slide it over 50% of the width of the element, I want the element to slide automatically to a new position).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I finally found out what should be the correct way of solving this.

I decided to go for swipe gestures and to implement `onGestureListener` and there I found a lot of interesting methods.

That class can be found here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.html